# Combine two lists by appending the element of one list to the element of the other list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have two same length lists like `[[-3, -2, 1],[2,3,5],[1,2,3]...[7,8,9]]` and `[-1,1,1,...1]`. I would like to combine them as: `[(-3,-2,1,-1), (2,3,5,1), (1,2,3,1)...(7,8,9,1)]` in Python. 
Appreciate if any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [(-3, -2, 1),(2,3,5),(1,2,3), (7,8,9)]
>>> b = [-1,1,1, 1]
>>> [i+(j,) for i, j in zip(a, b)]
[(-3, -2, 1, -1), (2, 3, 5, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1), (7, 8, 9, 1)]
```

Comment: Tried but error message below:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-709a21a20266> in <module>()
----> 1 [L+(S,) for L, S in zip(l, s)]

<ipython-input-46-709a21a20266> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [L+(S,) for L, S in zip(l, s)]

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Comment: then your input is not the same, if you have lists instead of tuples in your list, then you need: [i+[j] for i, j in zip(a, b)]